# How to create mysql database using command prompt? I'm getting error ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ivs'

Tags: mysql

I want to create database in mysql I installed MySQL 5.6 in windows 8, During installation installer never asked me username or password. When I'm executing command "`create database ivs;`" it gives me following error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ivs' what can I do now?

Comment: Post your command that give this error

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: sorry, the commandline where your start mysql like mysql -u xxxx -h yyyyy. It looks that you are not connected to the server. can you do any other command at the mysql promt - SHOW DATABASES;

Comment: Oh !!! previously on hitting 'show databases' it displays me databases but I think now I lost connection to server how to connect now

Comment: I started MySQL using 'services.msc' but now on hitting command "create database ivs" it again gives me error 1044

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100880/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-bernd-buffen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have use the **default** User and not **root**. The default User dosent have enough right to Create Databases. Start the Client with root User

```
c:> mysql -uroot
```

Answer (score 0):

After great discussion with @Bernd Buffen I got solution for my problem, when I use 'create database ivs' I actually not logged in with 'root' user (I'm logged in with guest user)  so to change this to root I use following command:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -uroot
>   and then I use

```
 mysql> create database ivs; to create database named 'ivs'
```

Comment: Mark bernd buffen answer as the correct answer to help others.